# FUSE exFat error

Tags: exfat

I have Windows 7 along with a Fat64 partition holding most of my data. I then installed Ubuntu 12.04, and most things are fine. Of course, Ubuntu doesn't read exFat, so following [these instructions](http://apcmag.com/how-to-enable-exfat-in-ubuntu.htm) I ran

```
sudo -s
apt-add-repository ppa:relan/exfat
apt-get install fuse-exfat
```

followed by

```
cd /media
sudo -s
mkdir usbdrive
mount -t exfat /dev/sdd1 usbdrive
```

and got this error:

```
FUSE exfat 1.0.1
ERROR: `pagefile.sys' real size does not equal to size (0 != 8565587968).
```

How can I get this to mount?

Comment: In the end, I converted the (300 GB) partition to NTFS, by copying everything off, formatting, and copying back. Took ~16 hours

Comment: First make sure you have [enabled exFAT on Ubuntu](http://namhuy.net/872/how-to-enable-exfat-on-ubuntu.html), and your usb is formatted with exfat file system. If it's possible try to remove pagefile.sys in linux.

Comment: That's a great reference if I ever need to do it again.

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure your flash drive is formated with an exfat filesystem before you can mount it as an exfat file system. Also check the integrity of the format before using the device by using a standard partitioning program that has the capability to check for exFat format integrity. You'll have to search for such a program.

Also note that NTFS is reported to shorten the lifespan of flash drives due to using more read write operations on the device then Fat, Fat32, or exFat file systems do.

If you are moving files larger then 4GB to the device then exFat is a better choice noting that exFat has been reported to not be as well supported by Mac or Linux systems yet. Where "well supported" means the functionality is present and functioning without having to install extra tools or make extra configurations after a first install of the Operating System.

In the error you have shown, pagefile.sys is reporting a size of 0, when the mount program was expecting a size of 8565587968. This could mean a number of different things but in general this is due to the file system not being recognized correctly. For example this could mean that exFat isn't implemented correctly in Linux yet, or that the drive wasn't formated correctly to an exFat filesystem, or that something else went wrong.